# Rmd add extern .pdf-page to html report

Tags: html, pdf, markdown, r-markdown

Is it possible to include a specific page of a .pdf to an html-markdown report?

This works obviously, but only if the Rmd-report is rendered to .pdf

```
\includegraphics[page=2]{my.pdf}
```

For an html-report, nothing is included.

```
![my.plot.description](my.pdf)
```

includes the whole pdf as single, scrollable pdf inside the html-report.